# Parameter format issue with ASP.NET Web API controller

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am watching this pluralsight demo video on Web Api, and he is using fiddler to pass in a parameter using Http Get with the syntax of controller/parameter

So he's using `http://localhost:2405/api/values/5`

5 Is the parameter he's passing in.

In my code, I have everything set up exactly the same way he does... with a routing template of `{controller}/{id}` and a controller method with a signature of

```
public string Get(string zipcode)
```

I can pass a parameter just fine with `http://localhost:2405/api/values?zipcode=25252`  but if I try passing in a paramter the way he does, like `http://localhost:2405/api/values/25252` I get an error saying I do not have an action available to handle that request on the controller.

What is he doing right, that I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your routing template to `{controller}/{zipcode}` as the name of the parameter must match the name in the template.

Comment: Oh, duh! You know, I'm still learning this whole thing, so I thought the {id} field was some sort of keyword that is used by reflection, like {controller}. Thank you so much!

Comment: I agree. It's not always intuitive which things are keywords and which are conventional 'magic'.